# RS and RR value in SDP

Tags: sdp

Somebody please clarify me following doubts.

1) why do we need to send AS value in invite sdp. Who will use this
value(volte servers/remote device). And how they use this value?

2)how to calculate AS value?

3) RS and RR values indicate bandwidth to be allocated to sender reports
and receiver reports. Can these be higher than AS?. As far I understand
these values should be lesser than AS. Please correct me if I am wrong.

4) effects of changing RS and RR values? What happens if we increase RS/RR?
Similarly what happens if we decrease RS/RR

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below link for the calculation of AS Value.
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/voice/voice-quality/7934-bwidth-consume.html